# Correct pronunciation of the name Geoff

Tags: pronunciation

What's the correct pronunciation of the name Geoff? Is it like "Jeff" or more like "GEE-off" or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's another way to spell Jeff, and is pronounced the same way.

They're both short for Geoffrey (often spelled Jeffrey), both of which are pronounced like the second spelling — JEF-ree. (The IPA form, in case you're familiar with that, is /ˈd͡ʒɛfɹi/.)

Comment: I have a friend who spells it Geoffery, but pronounce it Jeff-ree

Answer (score 2):

It is however the Person named Geoff tells you how to pronounce it.

People can spell their names different ways and pronounce them in all kinds of different ways, that even do not look like their spelling. People might not be able to get away with this except that Engish already has almost no spelling rules. And since English spelling is so erratic anyway, *Names* can get even further away from whatever rules we have.

Comment: This is not exactly wrong, but in actual practice, at least 90% of names you'll run across follow approximately the same pronunciation patterns you'd expect if you learned English names a hundred years ago. And usually, people do not change pronunciation of conventionally-spelled names to some strange idiosyncrasy: they change *spelling* of some conventionally-*pronounced* name to something "original" or "unique". So Caitlin becomes Kaytlyn, Geoff becomes Jef, and so forth. Harder to read, but not actually a different name once spoken.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - "**Geoff becomes Jef, and so forth. Harder to read, but...**" - Did you mean to say "Jeff becomes Geoff"?

Comment: @brilliant: No; I was going by original etymology. "Jeff" is certainly easier to read than its root, but most such creative spellings are less so.